# django model not creating postgresql table

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have added a simple model to my reporter app in my django project

```
class Municipalities(models.Model):
    namelsad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    geom = gismodels.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
```

when I `python3 manage.py makemigrations reporter`

it says `no changes detected in reporter`

then when I `python3 manage.py migrate reporter`

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: reporter
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

but there is no postgresql database table of reporter_municipalities

reporter is included in installed apps

Municipalities model is in the model.py file in reporter app

I should add I had a counties table and manually deleted it in postgresql and tried adding the municipalities model to create a table

municipalities is also in the django_content_type

[image]

but there is no table of municipalities

**update**

Changed `Class Municipalities` to `Class Muni`

`python3 manage.py makemigrations reporter`

then it asked me

```
Did you rename the reporter.Municipalities model to Muni? [y/N]
```

if I click y

then run migrate

gives me

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "reporter_municipalities" does not exist
```

but I am so confused that table does not and never existed!!

I cannot migrate at all to the DB now because of "reporter_municipalities"

Comment: Did you included the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes it is in installed apps

Comment: What file did you declare the model `Municipalities` in?

Comment: @RedCricket model.py

Comment: Would you mind deleting your `migrations` directory from `reporter` app, and then do `makemigrations` and `migrate` respectively?

Comment: @KishorPawar tried this...same problem

Comment: Along with directory, you will have to truncate migrations table also.

Answer (score 1):

When Django looks for migrations, it searches for the app `reporter` as is it configured in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. It uses `AppConfig` or application name to retrieve the full package name, ie `my_project.reporter`. This package must be available in your `PYTHONPATH`. It should be available only in you development project, but could happen that it is "installed" in your virtualenv. It can happen running `pip install .`  (without `-e`) or (with some configurations) running tests (I have seen this happen with tox).

In this scenario you have two `my_project.reporter` available to python, but you edit/update the "second" one. When you run `./manage.py makemigrations`, python first find the code that you did not change (the installed one in your virtualenv), so it does not find the updates.

To check if you have this duplication, you can:

1. uninstall your project (`pip uninstall <django-project>`) to see if it refers to a "symbolic link"

   If this is the case you will see something like 

   `Uninstalling <PROJECT>:
   Would remove:
    /data/PROGETTI/UNICEF/odk/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/<PROJECT>.egg-link
   Proceed (y/n)? y`

   Note the `egg-link` at the end of the line.

OR

1. open a shell and type `import <full_path_of_reporter> AS pkg; print(pkg.__file__)` and check the filepath

Comment: I am also not sure what this would accomplish. It's not any installed pip app, it's a model within the Django project.

Comment: okay I will have to wait a few days until I am back at work, your explanation is a bit over my head. and I will add that my project is not in a virtual env

Comment: I couldn't figure this out -- luckily I was not so far into my project. I ended up switching over to a new postgres DB

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't give a very technical answer but I got round this my creating a table with the same name directly via pgAdmin. Making and running migrations. At this point the table was recognised but obviously didn't work correctly because it had no columns. I then commented out the model in models.py and made ran migrations which removed the table. I checked on pgAdmin that the table had been removed by this point. I then deleted the migrations files (no idea if this was necessary), uncommented the model in models.py and then made and ran migrations again. Worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the question but for people facing this in future, there are files inside the *pycache* folder inside the migrations folder with .pyc extension. Just delete those files if they are already there and run from starting, i.e., start from makemigrations again and hopefully  you'll get it. I got it the same way by deleting the files in migrations folder other than *init* and deleting the files inside pycache folder other than *init*.

Answer (score 0):

ty running python ./manage.py makemigrations "app_name" as the last argument, then the migrate command. this worked for me when having the same issue.